# How to show multiple images using retrofit android

Tags: android, web-services

Hello below is my image ulrs thats comes from backend services. The images are separated with comma(,). Please let me know how can i separate each images and set them to imageView.

Below is the url

```
    {"data":[{"title":"Manali","organizer":"SINGH","image":",
Img_5c3ff5642013e20190117_084929.jpg,
Img_5c3ff564204b720190117_085027.jpg,
Img_5c3ff564206abPhoto_1547695381805.png,
Img_5c3ff56420e2f20190117_084853.jpg,",
"date1":"21 Apr 2019",
"date2":"24 Jan 2019",
"time1":"10:30AM",
"time2":"2:00PM",
"address":"VASANT VIHAR D-BLOCK MARKET NEW DELHI",
"city":"Delhi",
"state":"Delhi",
"price":"7000"}
]
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `string.split(",");`

Comment: thakns prashant your answer works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextUtils.split(",", fullImageString);` will give you the images in a string array, and depending on how to use them you can show the images fetching the values from what you created. It is not possible to show multiple images in one `ImageView` however you can show multiple images with `GridView`, `ListView` or `RecyclerView` that holds multiple `ImageView` references, with using an adapter and such. If these are image URLs, use [this library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to efficiently process each URL and display them on image views, while working with list adapters.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the urls, you would do the following :

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resultFromWebservice);

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject innerObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String imgURLs = innerObj.getString("image");

            ArrayList urlList= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(imgURLs.split(",")));

            for (int j = 0; j < urlList.size(); j++) {
                Log.d("Extracted URLs", "myMethod: " + urlList.get(j));
                // You can set the imageView urls from here
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```